# Anchors in WordPress not followed/ indexed in sitemap.xml

Tags: seo, nofollow, google-xml-sitemaps

Have anchor tags on a WordPress page about 300 on a page which are not listed in sitemap.xml, these links are generated dynamically. How do I index these?

Structure: A navigation link say **Games** when clicked --> Opens **List of Games (Football, Basketball etc.)** when clicked Football it opens --> Different versions of the games.

These are not listed in the sitemap.xml when created from online sitemap generators.

When clicked them manually in pages they open but doesn't appear in sitemap.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Why should anchors be part of a sitemap? Sitemaps show the general structure of the website, not "jumping points" within them.

Comment: You should contact the author of the service generating the sitemap and ask him

Comment: @flomei Because they're like **products(Jeans)** page where I have to list them and they're **dynamic**. I want google to index my page with all those Jeans listed. What approach should I follow then?

Comment: @flomei problem solved, Joel answer worked, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not index anchor tags, only URLs.  (Note that by anchor tags, I assume you mean a URL like **site.com/page.html#anchor**)

The solution is to create a separate, static URL that displays the same content as what you would get with the anchor tag - for instance **site.com/page-anchor.html**.

Then you can just create a page with links to all these new URLs, and Google will follow those links nearly as efficiently as with a sitemap file.  Or manually edit a sitemap.xml file and upload it to your server for Google to index.

Comment: they are internal links displayed but they're not static but dynamic

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, The process you defined is followed. (Anchors)They are internal links displayed on a static page **site.com/page-anchor.html** and the anchors are not static but **dynamic** like a products page. But sitemap is not generated of those links(i.e. the anchors).

Comment: Have you tried just making static links to the dynamic pages? It doesn't matter if the content is dynamic - you just need a static link and static URL for Google to index.  It doesn't really matter if there is a sitemap - that's just a hint to Google.  If there are no links, then your sitemap generator isn't able to find the pages, either.

Comment: +1  @joel Thanks for the answer you suggested found me the solution. And yes there was a problem in my reference in providing the dynamic links. Worked when applied your answer

Comment: @NikeshNagpal You're welcome - glad it worked out.  Could you please accept the answer?